# Getting Issue while using quiz module

Tags: quiz

I am new to **drupal** and I am realy stuck.
Module - [Quiz](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz) 
The scenario is - While taking quiz from app suppose i left it in middle and resume it from web then it is working fine but when i ends the quiz through my app it gives the result but again if i open it in web it goes to last question.

Pls provide some solution.

Thanks